# Generic nested class function in Free Pascal

Tags: freepascal

I tried writing the following to see if I could simulate generic methods in Free Pascal 3 by combining its support for generic class functions and nested classes:

```
{$mode delphi}
type TFoo = class
  public
    type TBar<T> = class
      class function Min(const A, B: T): T;
    end;
end;
class function TFoo.TBar<T>.Min(const A, B: T): T;
begin
  if A < B then
    Result := A
  else
    Result := B;
end;
```

I have tried several syntactical variations, but I can't get it to compile no matter what. In this form, the compiler gives me a fatal error on line 8 (`method identifier expected`, `Syntax error, ";" expected but "<" found`).

What is the proper syntax for this, if at all possible?

Comment: Works fine in Delphi, so it must be a FreePascal bug.  Ask in the [FreePascal forums](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/), and if needed [file a bug report](https://bugs.freepascal.org).

Comment: @Remy, how `A < B` can work for `T` _anywhere_? If you find this compilable in Delphi, you should file a bug report to EMBT ;-)

Comment: @Victoria:  `A < B` doesn't work without type-casting (and with a type-cast, the code works fine in Delphi), but that is not the issue in question.  The error is on `class function TFoo.TBar<T>.Min(const A, B: T): T;` and that compiles in Delphi.

Comment: @Remy, that's what I reliazed. Just not worth saying _this works fine_ in Delphi (for future visitors) ;-) But yes, I agree, I could reproduce the same issue with FPC 3.0.2 compiler.

Comment: Compilable and works in FPC trunk BTW.

Comment: FPC trunk and Delphi both have support for generic methods though, so this becomes pointless. I've been trying to do this in `objfpc` mode lately, and I'm starting to think it's impossible in FPC 3.0.

Comment: "FPC trunk" is the latest development version, 3.1.1 at the time. There are also several 3.0 versions: 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.4 as I remember. Which version you are using exactly? `fpc -iV` in command line.

Comment: I'm using 3.0 like I mentioned in my previous comment, but more specifically 3.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct and working syntax in fpc 3.0.4, at least in mode objfpc (mode delphi not tested):

```
{$mode objfpc}
type TFoo = class
  public
    type generic TBar<T> = class
      class function Min(const A, B: T): T;
    end;
end;
class function TFoo.TBar.Min(const A, B: T): T;
begin
  ...
end;
```